# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in

Tags: php, function, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm getting this error and I can't make head or tail of it.

The exact error message is:

```
function kdrusha_theme_create_page() {
    require_once(get_template_directory().= '/inc/pages/kdrusha-settings.php');
}

add_menu_page("KD Rusha Options", 'KD Rusha', 'manage_options', 'kdrusha-options', 'kdrusha_theme_create_page','',99);
```

Comment: Why is there an `=` in there?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `.=`.

```
something .= something_else
```

is shorthand for

```
something = something . something_else
```

But your `something` is a function call, and it generally doesn't make sense to assign to a function call (the exception is when it returns a reference).

You should just use `.`, which concatenates its parameters and returns the result without assigning it anywhere.

```
require_once(get_template_directory() . '/inc/pages/kdrusha-settings.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your function return in some variable:

```
function kdrusha_theme_create_page() {
    $template = get_template_directory();
    require_once($template.'/inc/pages/kdrusha-settings.php');
}
```

Comment: Now getting me other error that says (add_menu_page("KD Rusha Options", 'KD Rusha', 'manage_options', 'kdrusha-options', 'kdrusha_theme_create_page','',99);)